# How do you do Swing's JSplitPane in SWT?

Tags: swing, swt, jsplitpane

I am looking for an SWT widget that would have the look and behavior similar to Swing's JPlitPane. Is there such a widget in SWT, and if not, what's the closest to it?
(A pane split to two with the ability to move the border between the two parts)

Comment: Sash?  http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the SashForm:

From the javadoc...

*The SashForm is a composite control that lays out its children in a row or column arrangement (as specified by the orientation) and places a Sash between each child. One child may be maximized to occupy the entire size of the SashForm. The relative sizes of the children may be specified using weights.*

[SashForm example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet109.java)